# Copy from csv with default values

Tags: postgresql

I have CSV file to import in PostgreSQL table with many columns.
I firstly create a temporary table in which then copy CSV file...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mylist;
CREATE TEMP TABLE mylist (a text, b text, c text, d text, e text, f text, 
                      g text, h text, i text, j text, k text, l text,
                      m text, n text, o text, p text, q text, r text, 
                      s text, t text, u text, v text, w text, 
                      CONSTRAINT popisp_pkey PRIMARY KEY(A));

COPY mylist FROM 'C:\temp\popisp1.csv' DELIMITER AS ';' CSV;
```

This copies data into table but additional problem appear. In fields where is no any data seems that Null is copied but I need an empty string ('').

Is here any way to get empty string where is no data in table cell automatically?
I was try to add DEFAULT '' to every column declaration but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `NULL` parameter with a string that for sure does not appear in the file:

```
COPY mylist FROM 'C:\temp\popisp1.csv' DELIMITER AS ';' NULL '<<>>' CSV;
```

Per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html):

> NULL
>
> Specifies the string that represents a null value. The default is \N (backslash-N) in text format, and an unquoted empty string in CSV
>   format. You might prefer an empty string even in text format for cases
>   where you don't want to distinguish nulls from empty strings. This
>   option is not allowed when using binary format.

Or use [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL):

```
update mylist set
    a = coalesce(a, ''),
    b = coalesce(b, ''),
--    ...
    w = coalesce(w, '');
```

Comment: I find that by myself. But it is not much 'automatic' :)

Comment: Ok, I have another proposition ;)

Comment: Hm, I see this first time now! It works partially. Columns where all cells are empty are not filled with ''. Can you improve that?

Comment: Finally, I have to use Coalesce method for wanted result. Anyway, thanks for helping!

Comment: Is there a place in documentation where I can read more about "NULL '<<>>'" expression?